# Concatenate numbers separated by dash while keeping leading zeros

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have two columns in Excel with leading zeros that I want to concatenate. The below code works perfectly. It concatenates the columns and retains the leading zeros from each column:

```
= A2&B2
```

However, I need a dash between the values. When I alter the formula to the following the leading zeros to the right of the dash are removed:

```
= A2&-B2
```

How do I add that dash while retaining all leading zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Excel's CONCATENATE formula.

`=CONCATENATE(A2,"-",B2)`

Here, I use `00df9` in cell `A2` and `00asd` in cell `B2` with a result of `00df9-00asd`

Comment: Using this formula, if the cell has leading zeroes they get truncated after the concatenate function.

If cell A2 = FOO and B2 = 001, CONCATENATE(A2,"-",B2) yields FOO-1, not FOO-001.

Answer (score 0):

if I've used two separate formulas using concatenate into one cell and both or one brings answer with decimals, how can I format to limit or remove (roundoff) the result numbers?

Here's the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE((F2/4.2),"/",((F2/4.2)/7))
and here's the example result: 273.809523809524/39.1156462585034
```

Now, for me, the idea solution is that the cell shows 234/39. Basically how (if at all) can I format that cell with concatenate formula?

Comment: Wrap the cell references with int(), i.e.:
=CONCATENATE((INT(F2/4.2)),"/",((int(F2/4.2))/7))